# Set min Android API in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I set the build target to Android 4.3, which has an API Level of 18. I updated my Android so it's running API 18 on Android version 4.3. The ADB recognizes my device. Yet when I run my application, it says it can't find any devices with min API 19. How can I make sure it looks for devices with min API 18?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure you set your min API in your manifest, not just in your project build target section? May cause some issues

Comment: that's in your manifest, not in the eclipse properties editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only setting the API level with which you are compiling your app. This should always be the latest SDK version. This won't affect with which minimum SDK version you can run your app.

You have to set the minimum SDK version in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18">
```

It's API 18 in this case, but I assume you want to support older API's as well. Most people either only support ICS+ (API 14+) or go from down to GB (API 10+) all the way up.

Answer (score 1):

The build target is the SDK that uses to compile your source.
You must verify the min SDK on the manifest file and ensure that its 18 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the target SDK is set to 18 in your application manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Sure should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you have selected is `targetVersion`

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
           android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
           android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

`maxSdkVersion` is rarely used, it's used commonly when you have [multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html) for your project and [target different API levels](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```